# Make httprequest to insert google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, tornado

I am using Tornado web and i am trying to use httpclient to make a http request to insert an event into Google Calendar. But i always get 400 bad request error. Could you help me on this? Thanks!

```
    event = {
         'start': {
                  'date': '2012-07-11'
                  },
         'end':   {
                  'date': '2012-07-12'
                  },
            }
    body = urllib.urlencode(event)
    http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer '+access_token}
        req =   tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url="https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key="+self.settings["google_developer_key"],
                                         method="POST",
                                         body=body,
                                         headers=headers)
        http_client.fetch(req, callback=self.insert_event_response)
```

Here are the error i got:

```
    HTTPResponse(code=400,request_time=None,buffer=<io.BytesIO object at     0x1bb3470>,_body=None,time_info={},request=<tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest object at 0x1ccc310>,effective_url='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key=AIzaSyAyy9M1HZ1nDMdBwGMPDLamhFkCB8iQEJ0',headers={'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Expires': 'Wed, 11 Jul 2012 03:19:29 GMT', 'Server': 'GSE', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 'Date': 'Wed, 11 Jul 2012 03:19:29 GMT', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},error=HTTPError('HTTP 400: Bad Request',))
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally make it work, the header need to be:

```
    headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer '+access_token, 'X-JavaScript-User-Agent':  'Google       APIs Explorer', 'Content-Type':  'application/json'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the body has to be `urllib` encoded and not `json` encoded?

Comment: here is the event:  {'start': {'date': '2012-07-5'}, 'end': {'date': '2012-07-5'}}     and the body with urllib encode is    
start=%7B%27date%27%3A+%272012-07-5%27%7D&end=%7B%27date%27%3A+%272012-07-5%27%7D

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that from Google API docs, it looks like the body must be JSON encoded, not  urlencoded. So: `body = json.dumps(event)`.